# How to enable 3D acceleration on Windows VM in virtual machine manager

Tags: windows-10, kvm-virtualization, hardware-acceleration, virt-manager

I have tried setting Type to Spice server and opengl on in display Spice and in Video Virtio setting the model to Virtio and 3D acceleration on, but that made the Windows VM unusable because of the lag.

Display spice settings:

[image: Display spice settings]

Video Virtio:

[image: Video Virtio]

Does anyone know how to enable 3D acceleration for a Windows VM?

Comment: Hi, the 3d acceleration you configured via spice+virtio isn't real hardware (gl passthrough, needs guest drivers not available on windows). Please compare the various passthrough options at https://cpaelzer.github.io/blogs/006-mediated-device-to-pass-parts-of-your-gpu-to-a-guest. You either need an extra GPU to pass or you need to setup mediated devices on your GPU to shard and pass a fragment of it. Could you check if that way would work for your setup?