# How do I get 3D acceleration to work in virt-manager?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, virtualization, virt-manager

I'm trying to get 3D acceleration to work in virt-manager, but no matter what guest I use in virt-manager, if I enable 3D acceleration, [I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D37rE.png).

In the details of the error, it has this:

```
Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2023-04-14T06:53:32.967256Z qemu-system-x86_64: egl: eglInitialize failed
2023-04-14T06:53:32.967390Z qemu-system-x86_64: Failed to initialize EGL render node for SPICE GL

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 108, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1384, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1353, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2023-04-14T06:53:32.967256Z qemu-system-x86_64: egl: eglInitialize failed
2023-04-14T06:53:32.967390Z qemu-system-x86_64: Failed to initialize EGL render node for SPICE GL
```

Here are the settings I have configured for my virt-manager instance:

Video:

```
<video>
  <model type="virtio" heads="1" primary="yes">
    <acceleration accel3d="yes"/>
  </model>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
</video>
```

Graphics Type:

```
<graphics type="spice">
  <listen type="none"/>
  <image compression="off"/>
  <gl enable="yes" rendernode="/dev/dri/by-path/pci-0000:05:00.0-render"/>
</graphics>
```

What does `egl: eglInitialize failed` and `Failed to initialize EGL render node for SPICE GL` mean? How do I fix this error? And why does this occur? Am I missing something important?

And just to confirm, I have checked to see if I've got virtualisation enabled in GRUB with the `grep CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub` command, and yes I do:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_iommu=on iommu=pt splash"
```

The GPU I'm using for the host machine is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950, with the latest proprietary nvidia driver installed. And it is the only GPU I have.

I've even tried running `DRI_PRIME=1 virt-manager`, but it doesn't work.

I've even looked everywhere for this error, and even looked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348975/how-to-use-opengl-3d-acceleration-in-virt-manager-with-ubuntu) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383850/how-to-enable-3d-acceleration-on-windows-vm-in-virtual-machine-manager).

I've even looked [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/sewiph/virtmanager_giving_spice_gl_error/), but that solution didn't work.

How do I get 3D acceleration to work in virt-manager?

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: 22.04.2 LTS is the version I'm using, latest LTS release. Memory is 16.0 GiB, processor is Intel® Core™ i3-6100 CPU @ 3.70GHz × 4.

Comment: Hi, been trying to fix this for a while, but always came to the conclusion that it's not supported by Nvidia. You could theoretically try it with mesa drivers, but I haven't tried that since I'm using software which requires close sourced drivers. Anyways, if you find a solution, please let me know!

Comment: on AMD video cards this works out of the box .... swap to nvidia can do this anymore  ....

Comment: it's not compatile because they have a comercial version of it vgpu ... you can get for free for 90 days :( but this sucks ... if i own the gpu why they lock this function in order to use they paid software ?

Comment: or i got wrong driver instaled : https://docs.nvidia.com/grid/13.0/grid-vgpu-release-notes-generic-linux-kvm/index.html or unsuported video card.